# How to delete message using Telegram API (not BOT API!)

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I need to delete specific message (TL.Message msg) from my chat.
I'm trying to use `var aff = await _tgSession.TgClient.Messages_DeleteMessages(new int[1] { msg.id });`
but it do nothing.

this is understandable because I don't send the chat ID anywhere.

Is any other way to delete message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the helpful tooltips when you're programming:
[image: tooltip]
and read the essential [README](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/) about Terminology

`Messages_DeleteMessages` is only for legacy basic chats / user chats.
`Channel_DeleteMessages` is for groups & channel

even better: use helper `client.DeleteMessages(...)` that works in any of those cases.